# Installing pyodbc on redhat

Tags: redhat, pyodbc

I am trying to install pyodbc on Redhat. I know that for pyodbc you need the unixODBC-devel. However if I have the sql server odbc driver installed on my server do I still need unixODBC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about this driver?

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36437

If you're using that, it is a drop in for unixODBC, however, the installation instructions seem to require you to have unixODBC, and then perform a "drop in" installation. Too bad there isn't something in yum.